# Symmetry of two-electron wave function under electron exchange

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry

Consider two electrons in some potential. The typical reasoning for the wave function having to be (anti)symmetric goes like this -

> The Hamiltonian remains unchanged under electron exchange. Therefore, the wave function $u(r_1,r_2)$ must satisfy $$u(r_2,r_1)=x u(r_1,r_2),$$
> and since exchanging the electrons twice brings us back to the original state, $x^2=1$, so $x=\pm 1$.

I have no problem with the second step ($x^2=1$). And it is clear to me that the condition $u(r_2,r_1)=x u(r_1,r_2)$ makes sure that $u(r_2,r_1)$ satisfies the Schroedinger equation.

But - how do we know that $u(r_2,r_1)=x u(r_1,r_2)$ is a *necessary* condition? For example, why can't $u(r_2,r_1)$ be the complex conjugate of $u(r_1,r_2)$, instead of a multiple? Or, one could imagine some kind of spacial flip of the wave function that doesn't correspond to a multiplication by $\pm1$. What rules that out?